# can not reference Py_Initialize using c invoke python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-extension

I want to use a c program invoke a python program,

os:ubuntu 12.10 x64
python2.7.3

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_SetProgramName("c_python");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print \"Hello world,Python!\"\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    exit(0);
}
```

compile shell:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -Wall -fPIC c_python.c -o c_pyton


/tmp/cciuHgrf.o：in ‘main’：
c_python.c:(.text+0x1c)：reference undefined ‘Py_Initialize’
c_python.c:(.text+0x28)：reference undefined ‘Py_SetProgramName’
c_python.c:(.text+0x3e)：reference undefined ‘Py_Finalize’
collect2: error： ld return 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the Python interpreter into your executable: `-lpython`.